# CSS: Set divs horizontally in 2 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

Lets say I have

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="single">1</div>
    <div class="single">2</div>
    <div class="single">3</div>
    <div class="single">4</div>
    <div class="single">5</div>
    <div class="single">6</div>
    <div class="single">7</div>   
</div>
```

What I want to have is to plase the .single divs in 2 rows like bricks horizontaly from left to right this simple way: 1st div will be in left top corner, 2nd will be placed below 1st, 3rd will be placed next to 1st, 4th will be placed below 3rd and so on like:

```
1 3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8
```

All the divs has the same size.

I've tried with masonry.js and its working like a charm, but its way to complex solution for so simple task (simply solution is important).

[fiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/mwjJG/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a CSS property that does exactly that

http://tinker.io/8ff59

```
.cont {
    -webkit-columns: 5em;
    -moz-columns: 5em;
    columns: 5em; /* desired width of column */
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: it works in IE 10.. set a width to the container div like 400 px etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem and solved using the grid.

Here's the CSS you should add to your container:

```
.cont {
    height: 220px;
    background: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
    gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with css with structure as you have.

This structure should help you to get your required layout:

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b">
       <div class="c">1</div>
       <div class="c">2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="b">
       <div class="c">3</div>
       <div class="c">4</div>
   </div>
</div>


<style>
div.a div.b {float: left; width: 100px;}
</style>
```

Comment: It will propably work, but it changes structure of DOM and it may get tricky when goes about sorting etc. I was thinking about some nth css elements, but I'm not sure if its possible

Comment: do you need only two rows or more?

Comment: lets say 2, I'm not sure 100%, but we can assume that.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, let's say you can't change your document structure - you need to do this through layout definitions alone.

If you know how many items you will have, the easiest way to manage this would be CSS3 columns with inline-block elements. Your .singles are the inline-blocks, and .cont uses the 'columns' property to set 5 columns each wide enough to hold your singlets, whilst using max-height to force the inline-blocks onto new columns every two items. The singlets have a min-size large enough to stop multiple inline-blocks displaying on the same line.

You can see this effect as a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwjJG/25/ :

```
.container {
    height: 240px;

    columns: 100px 5;
    -webkit-columns: 100px 5;
    -moz-columns: 100px 5;
    }

.single {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    }
```

Do be aware this won't work on IE<10 unless you can use some kind of JS-based shiv to add support for the columns property (CSS Pie may be able to do this).

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this with CSS here using this code: It's kind of hackish though.

I set three of the divs (the last three) to the class 'double'

```
.cont .single {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.cont .double {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

div:nth-child(5) {
    clear:left;
}

.cont {
    height: 220px;
    background: red;
}
```